# Background Peeking Out of Border of Website

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to get rid of the red background from appearing around the left and bottom side of the website when the screen is maximized. I think it is because I am trying to overlay images on my fourth/last page named "Find Us", and the combined width of these images exceed 1400px which is the min-width I have set on the page.

A solution could be to increase the min-width, but I do not think this is a good design choice when a lot of computers are not running at such a high resolution. Ideally, I would like to bring the min-width down to 1100px. When I try doing so, the red background on the bottom of the page starts to increase more as it is trying to squeeze in the images in a tighter area.

I am wondering how I would get rid of the red background that is peeking out along the left and bottom borders of the website while reducing the min-width to 1100px.

Link to website: http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/it/website03/template.html

CSS:

```
.page {
    color: black; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 1100px;
    position: relative; }

#findUs .pageContent {
    width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto; }

#findUs #man #contactInfo {
    margin: 195px 0 0 345px;
    width: 200px; }

#findUs #frame {
    width: 464px;
    height: 541px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 130px;
    left: 190px;
    z-index: 90; }

#findUs #tassel {
    background: url(../img/findUs/tassel.png) no-repeat;
    width: 165px;
    height: 411px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -330px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 110; }

#findUs #feedbackForm {
    position: relative;
    top: -1100px;
    left: -470px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 120; }

#findUs #cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1100px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 105;
    background: url(../img/findUs/body.png) repeat; }
```

HTML:

```
<section id="findUs" class="page"> <!-- Last page -->
    <nav></nav>     
    <div class="pageContent">       
        <div id="man"><div id="contactInfo"><p class="infoHeading">Business Hours</p></div></div>       
        <div id="frame"><div id="googleMapCanvas"></div></div>
        <div id="tassel"></div>    
        <div id="feedbackForm"></div>           
    </div>      
    <div id="cover" class="hidden"></div>       
</section>
```

Comment: @AlexW My apologies. I just included the relevant code.

Comment: Have you tried this: `html, body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }` ?  One of the "general" problems I can see is that you're using `px` values instead of scalable values such as `%`'s.  You could also try using some `overflow: hidden` CSS to see if that helps.

Comment: I just tried `html, body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }` but it didn't work. I have also applied a CSS reset style guide. How does using `%` help?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the issue..(in chrome) where do you see the issue? (on a side note.. what is that scrolling effect called/how do you it?)

Comment: I see this issue in Chrome, Safari, IE, and Firefox. The problem is located along the right hand side of the entire side (1px of red gap) and on the very bottom of the last page (10px of red gap) - http://postimage.org/image/47poog5z1/ .

Comment: I've uploaded a sample of this effect at http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/parallaxTest/parallax01/parallax01.htm. It involves using `#firstPage{background:url(01.png) no-repeat fixed` and `<section id="firstPage">...</section`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the body background red? If not:

```
body {
background: transparent;
min-width: 1400px;
}
```

Comment: Nope I do not need the background to be red as originally the background was black which is why I did not notice my problem in the first place. My problem is that I do not want any bit of the background to peek out while reducing the `min-width:1400px` to `min-width:1100px`.